# LibGDX 3D Camera spasm when player looks directly up or down

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, perspectivecamera

### My circumstance

I am making a 3D LibGDX game. I am using a custom camera controller, based off of the one over [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/FirstPersonCameraController.java). It takes out the use of delta Y, when determining where to move the player, so that they can stay on the same level whether they are looking up or down.

### My problem

My problem is that whenever the player looks too far up, or down, the camera kinda starts spazing out. I believe that it is trying to look either strait up, or down. My problem is that I don't want that. In previous projects I have tried to set a limit like so:

```
if(camera.direction.y + deltaY >= 0.9){
    return;
}
```

(Code might not be exactly correct), but when that happens, the player usually cannot see enough.

### My code

There is a link to my code [here](http://pastebin.com/Amq3kBaV).

Comment: What happens if you do the following:

Vector3 right = camera.position.sub(camera.direction).crs(up).nor();
camera.rotateAround(camera.position, right, deltaY);
camera.rotate(Vector3.Y, deltaX);

You first get the right vector and rotate the camera around its own right vector, (up-down) and then rotate around it's Y-Axis. Never had trouble with that.

Comment: Sound like you are experiencing a `Gimbal Lock`. You should look into Quaternions to manipulate the camera or restrict it from looking completely up and down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my code fixed with the help of one of the fine fellows over at Github. Here is my new `FirstPersonCameraController#touchDragged`:

```
float deltaX = -Gdx.input.getDeltaX() * degreesPerPixel;
float deltaY = -Gdx.input.getDeltaY() * degreesPerPixel;
camera.direction.rotate(camera.up, deltaX);
Vector3 oldPitchAxis = tmp.set(camera.direction).crs(camera.up).nor();
Vector3 newDirection = tmp2.set(camera.direction).rotate(tmp, deltaY);
Vector3 newPitchAxis = tmp3.set(tmp2).crs(camera.up);
if (!newPitchAxis.hasOppositeDirection(oldPitchAxis))
    camera.direction.set(newDirection);
```

(I removed a couple of parts that are specific to my game)